# How to set a DB value to Nothing with Linq?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have an interesting problem. I'm using visual basic and before saving a row with Linq, I want to set it to nothing, for instance:

```
element.def = Nothing
```

But, when I save the element I have a 0 in the database instead of Null. Does anybody know how should I save my item so that `element.def = Null`?

This is an update, element.def previously had a value and element.def is of Integer? type, so it should be possible to save it as null.

Thank you in advance,
Lajos Arpad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `System.DBNull` instead.

```
element.def = System.DBNull
```